# Creating a state diagram from high level description

Tags: computation-theory

For the language L  = {ww | w∈{a,b}*} over Σ={a,b}

For the high level description I wrote,

"1. Place marker in front

2. Sweeping back and forth, check if length is even, if odd reject.
3. Place marker at end
4. Sweeping back and forth, move each marker towards the middle. Compare each letter, erase if equal, reject is not.
5. If markers meet in the middle, accept."

I just have no idea how to turn this turing machine into a state diagram.

Comment: It seems to me that you read the second w in reverse, because you start comparing it from the end,

Comment: Peter is right. You need to (a) ensure the input has even length and (b) find the beginning of the 2nd half of the string. Once you identify the two halves, then you will want to check them against each other in the same order, forward or reverse. If you'd like to see a state machine for a correct TM for the language, update your question.